# Is the MySQL password function vulnerable to this?

Tags: mysql, security, hash, passwords

Is storing a password in the DB using MySQL's password function just as bad as this?

http://money.cnn.com/2012/06/06/technology/linkedin-password-hack/?source=linkedin

> The problem with SHA-1 is that it translates the same text the same way each time. So if your password is "password" and your friend's password is also "password," they will be hashed exactly the same way. That makes reversing the process to uncover the original password significantly easier.

I know it says SHA-1, but obviously any unsalted one way hash would have the same issue.

Comment: Yep, any unsalted hash is vulnerable to a "rainbow table"-style attack.

Comment: This applies to all hash functions and is a desired behavior. It’s call determinism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is storing a password in the DB using MySQL's password function just as bad as this?

Yes.

Generally speaking you want to use a method that includes a salt, preferably unique for  each user, and is slow to run to prevent brute force cracking. [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is the currently recommended way to go when storing passwords because it is intentionally (relatively) slow to create.

Comment: Did you mean Blowfish, which isn't a hashing algorithm?

Comment: Yes. I wikipedia'd it and it is a cipher which is different. I updated my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: I guess you’re confusing Blowfish and bcrypt.

Comment: +1. I didn't know bcrypt was based on Blowfish, hence the confusion.

Comment: So Bcrypt plus a random salt? Bcrypt by itself doesn't have a salt right? Also, is bcrypt reversible/decryptable? Wouldn't that make it less secure?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) says that you shouldn't be using the PASSWORD() function in your own application:

> The PASSWORD() function is used by the authentication system in MySQL
>   Server; you should not use it in your own applications.

Internally, MySQL's PASSWORD() function utilizes SHA1(2), that's SHA1 twice. However, it doesn't utilize a salt. So, yes, it's still vulnerable to [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks.